# How to navigate to existing Fragment from BackStack?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a bunch of fragments using a single activity as host.

My fragments  are arranged like this,

Frag1 -> (Press Next) -> Frag2 -> (Press Next) -> Frag3 -> (Press Next) -> Frag4

In Frag1, I have a another button which will directly navigate to Frag4.

In Frag4, If I click back button it is currently going back to Frag1.
But Here I want this to navigate to Frag3.

Comment: You can replace fragment on the click of a button.

Comment: @Karan Mehta 
thanks for the reply. Here I want to achieve on back press.

Comment: @velusamy please update your answer with your activity code and nav graph also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got what you want correctly,
You can use popUpTo in Pop Behavior in the right side of your host xml where you connect fragments and navigate fragments and set popUpTo to a fragment that you want

or

you can use this code to say where to go when back button pressed:

> **Note**: you need to paste them in fragment class

```
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            add your navigation destonation or do whatever you want 
        }
```

you have another option too.

You can use:

```
view?.findNavController().popBackStack()
```

And last but not the least
If you are in activty class I mean not Fragment you can use this:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
do what you need
if you leave this fun empty, back button would not work any more        
}
```

I think ***second option*** is your fit

Comment: thanks for the reply.  In Frag4, I have tried like this   

`requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner) {
           view?.findNavController()?.navigate(R.id.Frag3)
            //view?.findNavController()?.popBackStack()
  }`

Frag4 -> (Press Next) -> Frag2 -> (Press Next) -> Frag3 -> (Press Next) -> Frag4

Comment: you dont need   view?.findNavController()?.popBackStack(). it is another way.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  In Frag4, I have tried like this   


now it is behaving like this,


Frag4 -> (Press back) -> Frag3 -> (Press back) -> Frag4 -> (Press back) -> Frag3  and so on.
.

Comment: you mean in fr4 when press back go to fr3 and press back again fr4?  does it repeate?

Comment: yes, it is looping.

Comment: so, post all fragment where you use this code

Comment: use third solution